# Why is my <p> tag getting closed automatically?

Tags: jquery, html, textarea

As you will see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bwmnyL6o/1/), I am placing a simple html string to a `textarea` on load and the string is equivalent to the following (more readable) version:

```
<p custom-attr-id='100'>
    <div>text 1</div>
</p>
<p custom-attr-id='101'>
    <div> text 2</div>
</p>
```

Placed just below the `textarea` is a `div` that displays the rendered string inside the `textarea`. If you pay attention to the above DOM structure, and click on the output area, you will notice that the `<div>text 1</div>` part no longer appears to be a child element of the `<p custom-attr-id='100'></p>`.

That's what I don't understand. The `<p>` tag should still be wrapping the `<div>`, but it somehow unwraps it and gets placed separately when all I did was display the content using jQuery's `html()` method. Is this a Fiddle behavior or the `html()` method?

Comment: A `<div>` isn't a valid child of a `<p>` element (which can, from memory, contain only 'phrasing content').

Comment: For those downvoted this, at least have the courtesy to explain why?

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing this the other way around. The code you displayed has a `div` inside of a `p` element. This is not valid as a `div` is a block element and `p` elements only allow for `inline` elements to be placed inside them.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html for more info.

Particularly the section:

`<!ELEMENT P - O (%inline;)*            -- paragraph -->`